# How to have some type of files open directly in a chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am using google chrome 77.0.3865.90 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 and I want to make chrome open some types directly in a browser tab.

For example text files with extension `.log` (example `out_L4PC.log`) are being opened directly in a broswer tab when I use an URL like `some/web/adress/out_L4PC.out`.

I have different files, also containing just text, but they end in `.err` (example `out_L4PC.err`). I want them to also open directly in the browser tab.

But so far, when I use such an `.err` file they are being downloaded and opened with a *different* application. This is not what I want. I do not want these type of files opened with a different application, but directly in the browser, just like `.log` files.

How to do that?

Comment: What is the desktop environment used in that Ubuntu installation?

Comment: According to `wmctrl -m` it is Compiz.

Comment: Could you expose one of these files *from your server*. It would help to know exactly the interaction between your server and Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different reasons for why Chrome (or any other browser) is downloading these files, instead of opening them in the browser:

- The hyperlink you clicked uses the `download` attribute, or the server responds with a `Content-Disposition: attachment` HTTP header - in both cases this tells the browser to download the file and save it to your local disk instead of displaying it.
- The resource you clicked returns (in the HTTP headers) a MIME type that the browser does not understand or cannot display (such as `application/octet-stream`).

Unfortunately, it seems Chrome itself offers no way to override this behavior.

For the first case (Content-Disposition header), you can use the Chrome extension [Undisposition](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undisposition/hjfncfijclafkkfifjelofbeclipplfi), which will remove this header, allowing you to display the document in the browser.  Note, however, that this will affect all links as long as the extension is active - so if you *do* want to download something, you'll have to disable the extension (or use "Save link as" from the context menu).

For the second case, I'm not aware of any method to disable Chrome's behavior.

You could, however, use Mozilla Firefox :-). For Firefox there's an extension which does what you want, [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/). If you click on a link that would normally trigger a download, it will pop up a dialog asking if you want to download or view in browser.

Comment: I see that the content-type in the response header is `text/plain` in one case (file opens directly in the browser) while for the other file (`err`) the content-type is `application/octet-stream`. So it might be server-related?

Comment: And the firefox extension works just fine. I just have to remember all the different cases when to use chrome, and when to use firefox...